# Como interactuar con un iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día, tardes o noches, tengo la duda de si es posible correr funciones desde un iframe, la situación es la siguiente, en mi trabajo brindamos un servicio de chat pero la pagina donde atendemos los chats tiene 2 ventanas para atender los chats, una de ellas esta protegida con iframe y la otra no, realizando pruebas veo que una función en js corre en ambas paginas, entonces yo programe una pagina propia en la que tengo un iframe y en ese iframe esta la pagina del chat que no esta protegida por el iframe, la cuestion es que la pagina que esta protegida de los iframes tiene el boton que cambia tu estatus de online a ofline y viceversa, ese botón detona la siguiente funcion "javascript:PortalUI.userStatus.saveStatus(this);" y me percato que por concola puedo correr la función en la otra pagina que no tiene el botón, mi pregunta es si desde mi pagina yo puedo integrar un botón que al dar clic te corra esa función

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede. Debes llamar al iFrame usando su ID, y llamando el objeto contentWindow de ese iframe:

#### HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="boton">Boton fuera del iframe</button>
<iframe id="iframe1" width="200" height="200">
    <body>Esto es un iframe</body>
</iframe>
```

#### JS:

```
function agregarScriptEnIframe(){
    let scriptNuevo = document.createElement('script');
    scriptNuevo.setAttribute('src','script_iframe.js');
    document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(scriptNuevo);
}

document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.alerta('Esta alerta del iframe se llamó desde afuera del iframe');
});
```

#### script_iframe.js:

```
function alerta(texto){
    alert(texto);
}
```

Comment: Hola que tal,esto es si existe el elemento en el html pero si no existe hay alguna manera de incrustar el html al iframe para crear el elemento y asi poder llamar la funcion?

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta para añadir la creación dinámica de un elemento `<script>` en el iframe

Comment: Si pero por ejemplo, este es mi iframe

<html>
<title>PRUEBA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
<body>
<button type="button" id="boton">Boton fuera del iframe</button>
<iframe id="iframe1" width="800" height="400"src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/support.sdplive637893146/subindex#portal/mycurrent">
</body>
</html>


De esa pagina yo quiero correr una funcion al dar clic en un botón de mi pagina pero la funcion no se encuentra en ningun elemento del iframe

Comment: Aquí cabe mencionar que si el atributo `src` del `iframe` no está en el mismo dominio (y subdominio) que el sitio principal, no será posible ejecutar funciones ni del padre al iframe, ni del iframe al padre. Se llama Cross-site Scripting y es una vulnerabilidad contra las que los navegadores te protegen. Podés ver más aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Eso va a ser por  que no me deja ejecutar la función y al parecer esta por medio de otra hoja script, aun asi me sirvio mucho la información, muchas gracias 8)